# New database in SQL Server 2008 does not show up in dropdown

Tags: visual-studio-2010, database-connection, sql-server-2008-express

I'm new to using Visual Studio and SQL Server.

My problem is this:

I have created a database in SQL Server Management Studio, then I'd like to connect it my app in Visual Studio. I right click in the Server Explorer and click on Add connection. Here I can find through dropdown list my server, but when selecting the database under "Connect to a database" it doesn't find my new database in the dropdown list...

Can you help me please? Thank you a lot :-)

Comment: Restart your SQL Server.......

Answer (score 0):

check whether it is windows authentication or server authentication in sql server 2008 where you have created the database. If it is server authentication then check whether you are entering correct username and password.

Comment: thank you for your answers, I tried to restart: nothing. I checked also and it is windows authentication... :-(